# windows scheduler to run a batch script (.bat) every x-minutes?

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to get windows scheduler to run a particular .bat script every 30 minutes or so, but the options only allow for once a day execution.

Is there a way I can get it to run a .bat script every 30 minutes?

Comment: `schtasks /create /?` see `/SC` parameter

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming question at all. VTC to superuser

Comment: @Matt It doesn't have to be a programming question. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic It falls in the category of "software tools commonly used by programmers" imo.

Comment: @Matt can't argue with that :)

Comment: It is on the Edit Trigger panel.  Repeat task every"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following to create a new scheduler

```
SCHTASKS /Create /SC MINUTE /MO 30 /TN MyTaskName /TR "c:/myBat.bat"
```

If you need additional settings, use

```
SCHTASKS /Create /?
```

Comment: I was looking into windows task scheduler but this works so thanks :)

Comment: @sks That is the schtasks is the cmd line interface for Windows tasks.